# Replace values in a Pandas data-frame using dictionaries stored in another data-frame matching the variable names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have a data-map in Pandas data-frame like this:

```
                                                      m  c  x
'V1'  {'0': 'absence', '1': 'mild', '2': 'moderate '...  1  5
'V2'      {'0': 'no ', '1': 'yes', '2': 'Not relevant'}  1  3
'V3'     {'1': 'smoker', '2': 'ex-smoker (not smoked)'}  1  6
```

where each cell in the column `m` has a dictionary of key-value pairs of the variable codes.

Now I have the tabular data in another data-frame like this:

```
         V1    V2    V3
'Sub1'   1.0   2.0   2.0
'Sub2'   0.0   0.0   NaN
'Sub3'   0.0   1.0   1.0
'Sub4'   1.0   NaN   2.0
```

I need to replace the values of the variables in the tabular data with the data-map codes. The expected output should be:

```
         V1          V2              V3
'Sub1'   'mild'      'Not relevant'  'ex-smoker (not smoked)'
'Sub2'   'absence'   'no '           NaN
'Sub3'   'absence'   'yes'           'smoker'
'Sub4'   'mild'      NaN             'ex-smoker (not smoked)'
```

Is there any elegant way to do this?